# how to jump from the page3 to page1 in a cardlayout in sencha2?

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch-2

I have a button in a form and on the click event of the button the card layout page moves backwards to the previous page.

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    id: 'promotionPanel',
    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'slide'
        }
    },
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            ui: 'light',
            title: 'Promotions',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                html: '<img src="../images/back_arrow.png">',
                ui: 'action',
                id: 'BtnBack',
                itemId: 'BtnBack',
                handler: function () {
                    Ext.getCmp('promotionPanel').setActiveItem('homePanel');
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                docked: 'right',
                html: '<img src="../images/home.png">',
                ui: 'action',
                id: 'BtnHome',
                itemId: 'BtnHome',
                handler: function () {

                }
            },
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            height: 480,
            width: 320,
            html: '<img src="../images/promotion.png" >',
            itemId: 'myimage',
        }
        ]
    }]
}
```

In this handler function, I have done the code for jump from the `promotionPanel` to the `homePanel`. But it will not come and two pages are overwritten. How can I solve this?

Comment: We need more information and/or code to help you. What is the third card? Can't you just call `setActiveItem('cardId')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can give Id to the button on that page, and below you can use listeners to give functionality of push to the next page or on whatever page you want.

If you need some sample code just let me know and I can help you out with that.